# ¿cómo hacer más grande el símbolo de sumatoria (sigma) dentro de una ecuación en LaTeX?

Tags: latex

```
% \begin{equation}
%   \hat{f}(x)= \frac{1}{nh} \displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^nK\left(\frac{x-x_i}{h}\right)   
% \end{equation}
```

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio. Echa un vistazo a esta respuesta en inglés a ver si te sirve: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22773/making-a-big-summation-sign